# Extracting form data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a form in an html email which posts to /review
The data in the submitted form comes from input fields in the form.

I use req.body to get the form data which appears as follows;

```
{ 
  customer_id: '52fa6ded48e3a50000000007',
  shop_name: 'sage-arts',

  'product-226039457-emotion': 'sucks',
  'product-226039457-comment': '1',

  'product-222924077-emotion': 'rocks',
  'product-222924077-comment': '12',

  'submit-review': 'Submit your review'
}
```

The `product-...-emotion` and `product-...-comment` pairs can be one or more, 2 in the above case.
I need to extract the pairs and process them no matter how many pairs there are.

I know that `customer_id` and `shop_name` are always the same, so i get them as follows;

```
var shop = form['shop_name'];
var customer = form['customer_id'];
```

But the rest have unpredictable keys. I tried

```
form[2];
```

But I get `undefined`

What would be a good way to extract the data i need without knowing the keys in advance?

Comment: Just loop over the object and test whether the key matches your `product-\d+-(emotion|comment)` pattern?

Comment: You can get a list of properties in the form object via Object.keys(form)

Comment: thanks guys, I've got it working now. I tried both methos Object.keys(form) gave me an array of all the keys, I also tried for(key in form) and was able to iterate over all the keys. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to iterate over the object and do some matching:

```
for(var field in req.body){
    if(field.match(/^product-\d+-emotion$/)){
        // do something with req.body[field]
    }
    if(field.match(/^product-\d+-comment$/)){
        // do something with req.body[field]
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that it would be helpful to transform this data so you have an object that is keyed by product IDs.  You could do something like this:

```
var products = {};
for(var field in req.body){
    var m;
    m = field.match(/^product-(\d+)-emotion$/);
    if(m) {
        var id = m[1];
        if(!products[id]) products[id] = {};
        products[id].emotion = req.body[field];
        continue;
    }
    m = field.match(/^product-(\d+)-comment$/);
    if(m) {
        var id = m[1];
        if(!products[id]) products[id] = {};
        products[id].comment = req.body[field];
        continue;
    }
}
```

If your fields are always in the form `product-99999-something`, you could make this even more general:

```
var products = {};
for(var field in req.body){
    var m;
    m = field.match(/^product-(\d+)-(\w+)$/);
    if(m) {
        var id = m[1];
        var prop = m[2];
        if(!products[id]) products[id] = {};
        products[id][prop] = req.body[field];
    }
}
```